# Fruity system of equations

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

I've seen a lot of these popping up in Facebook lately so I decided to make my own. Can you tell me what each symbol is?

[image]

There are no math errors in this puzzle.

In order for your solution to be correct it must work in all 4 equations.

Hint #1

> As pointed out by Silenus below, changing the equals sign would allow for many trivial solutions. So I will confirm that the equals sign represents equality. and also, numbers represent their actual numerical value.

Hint #2

> The only numbers that show up in the solution are positive integers.

Hint #3

> One of the fruit is not like the others. It represents a symbol on your keyboard which is neither a number nor a letter.

Hint #4

> Each symbol maps to a single character which could be found on an ordinary keyboard. This means that no numbers in the solution are larger than 9.

Hint #5

> The third equation has the string apple carrot banana, but if I reordered this expression to carrot apple banana, it would be nonsensical (it's a syntax error, something your calculator would not let you compute).

Comment: Does fruit right next to each other man multiplication or different digits of the same number?

Comment: Numbers next to each other multiply. So (10) (9) = 90 not 109.

Comment: Are you sure there are no mathematical errors? I'm getting multiple values for carrots.

Comment: Is star multiplication or something else?

Comment: The whole point of the facebook fruit math puzzle is that the fruit images aren't equal (for example some bananas are bunches of 4, others are 3). It's really more of a visual trick than a mathematical one. All of your fruit symbols are exactly the same. Is that really what you indended?

Comment: @wildBillMunson Each symbol behaves the same way every time it shows up. To solve this one you'll have to think outside the fruit basket.

Comment: These equations cannot all be true if the symbols represent constant values. Do they, rather, represent functions with variable outputs?

Comment: Can we assume all numbers are equal to their usual representation and that the equals sign denotes equivalence?

Comment: Guys try interpreting the + and * as variables too..

Comment: I've been trying to solve this with the fruits not representing a numerical value, but instead an action. For instance, letting apple = +3 and banana = +3 and carrot = +18, we get a remarkably close answer of everything working out apart from the last line equalling 78.

Comment: I've also tried using negative values, but that leads to the need for complex values that don't end up working out.

Comment: I can get a solution if 90 is replaced with 42...

Comment: @Deusovi that would be cheating, because 42 is the answer to everything

Comment: I have a solution if 90 is changed to 432

Comment: Or 153.5. Why is this so hard?

Comment: this could be anything... I believe you need to explain it in more detail for what symbols could refer to?

Comment: I've added a third hint

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with how these work on Facebook, are fruit/symbols allowed to map to more than one character or does each map to a single *digit* or *symbol*?  In other words is (**Apple=44**) a legal possibility? You say only positive integers appear in the solution, which *I think* precludes unary negation, but can you confirm? What about unary + for that matter? are we confined to basic arithmetic, or what about exponentiation or radicals?

Comment: What order of operations do the operations follow?

Comment: @Rubio Each symbol maps to a single character (none of the numbers in the solution are greater than 9). Exponention would be allowed since ^ is a single character, but a radical would not as there is no character for it.

Comment: @boboquack The math follows the normal order of operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The symbols are as follows:

> $$\begin{array}{rl}\bf{Apple:}&3\\\bf{Banana:}&1\\\bf{Carrot:}&\ ! \ \ \ \ (factorial)\\+:&+\\*:&4\end{array}$$
>
>  That gives:
>
>  $\ \ \ \ 3+3+3=9$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3·1·4·1·3=36$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3!·1·4·3!=144$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3·4!+3!·3=90$
>
>  all of which are true.
>  note:  $\ ·\ $  denotes multiplication due to adjacency, per OP comments.
>
>  Banana can also be $\times$ and still fulfill all the equations. Only a strict reading of **Hint 3** prevents it from being a solution (and I hadn't noticed that hint, so my original answer here used $\times$):
>
>  $\ \ \ \ 3+3+3=9$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3\times4\times3=36$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3! \times 4·3!=144$
>  $\ \ \ \ 3·4!+3!·3=90$
>
>  are all equally true as well.

Comment: Awesome, you got it!!! Side note: I originally make banana *, but realized later it could be 1 as well.

Answer (score 5):

From hints and comments we know that:

> - juxtaposition of variables or numbers means multiplication;
>
>   each symbol represents a symbol on the keyboard so that valid number replacements go from 0 to 9;
>
>   one symbol isn't a letter or digit;
>
>   the equals sign and the numbers on the right hand side represent themselves.

Further, let's assume that:

> - the plus sign really is the plus sign;
>
>   the asterisk does not mean multiplication, since that is already signalled by juxtaposition and
>
>   the asterisk represents a symbol or operator.

The replacements should then be:

> apple: 3
>   banana: 1
>   asterisk: 4
>   carrot: ! (exclamation mark)
>
>  The exclamation marks stands for factorial when put after an expression. That's why no expression can start with the carrot. The final equations are:
>
>      9 = 3 + 3 + 3
>    36 = 3·1·4·1·3
>  144 = 3!·1·4·3! = 6·1·4·6
>    90 = 3·4! + 6·3 = 3·24 + 6·3

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at this multiple ways and it appears to me that this puzzle's solution is:

> Non-existent

I determined this by solving each equation one by one.

The first equation can only be

> 3+3+3=9 as it's the same number the times

Thus the makes the second equation

> 3b*b3=36
>  So b =2

Here's where thing get complicated. If you solve the 144 equation first, you get

> Carrot =2.8... Give or take

But if you solve the 90 equation first, you get

> Carrot = 7.5

Here's a picture of my work (sorry if it's oversized I'm uploading this on mobile)

> [image: Math work]

Comment: Lateral thinking tag...

Comment: Didn't see it :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things, even lateral thinking and this equation simply cannot work, even by changing a fruit for (X,+,-,...) or even by changing the * symbol for another one.

The only way it works that I found is.

> Apple : 100
> Banana : 101
> Carrot : 102
> "+ symbol" : +
> "* symbol" : *
> "= symbol" : >
> The question did say to find the value of every symbols, not every fruit so... might be good.

Comment: If '=' means '>', the equations have infinite solutions for large values of the fruit, which is probably incorrect. I would think "find the value of every symbol" includes *at least* the fruit symbols *but possibly also* the mathematical operation symbols.

Comment: @Silenus I would agree with your first thought, but as for the second thought, I would go more with *definitely* includes the math symbols, seeing as it says "every symbol"

Comment: However, they did technically find a solution for each

Answer (score 0):

Partial -

First equation is ->

> Apple + Apple + Apple = 9

Hence -

> If Apple = 3 we get 3+3+3 = 9
>  **Apple = 3**

Second Equation is ->

> Apple Banana * Banana Apple

Hence - >

> If Banana = * and * = 4 we get 3*4*3 = 36
>  **Banana = *** and *** = 4**